# RuntimeError: size mismatch for embedding.weight in Tacotron2\inference.ipynb

Tags: pytorch, runtime-error, text-to-speech

I testing a tacotron2 trained model but getting an error.
Here are the code and errors.

```
checkpoint_path = "tacotron2_statedict.pt"
model = load_model(hparams)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(checkpoint_path)['state_dict'])
_ = model.cuda().eval().half()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 3
      1 checkpoint_path = "tacotron2_statedict.pt"
      2 model = load_model(hparams)
----> 3 model.load_state_dict(torch.load(checkpoint_path)['state_dict'])
      4 _ = model.cuda().eval().half()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\TTS\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:2153, in Module.load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict, assign)
   2148         error_msgs.insert(
   2149             0, 'Missing key(s) in state_dict: {}. '.format(
   2150                 ', '.join(f'"{k}"' for k in missing_keys)))
   2152 if len(error_msgs) > 0:
-> 2153     raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
   2154                        self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
   2155 return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Tacotron2:
    size mismatch for embedding.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([148, 512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([313, 512]).
```

Previously I had an error with Setup hparams and solved the problem following this link.
[HParams was removed from tensorflow 2.0](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2/issues/278)I don't know if this is related or not.(I'm new to this and this is my first question.)help me.

All libraries in `requirements.txt` are Latest version.
python==3.11 pytorch==2.2.1+cu118